# How can have website without local-storage or session-storage if connected with firebase?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication

I started my first website with firebase but I have some questions. Is the website with firebase need for local-storage or session-storage? How to keep the admin sign-in for all the pages (the currentUser on other pages is null)??

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not clear. Firebase Auth persists users in localStorage/indexedDB (default), sessionStorage or in-memory. You have the ability to choose either. For more on Auth state persistence, check: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence